# ReGex pattern output incomplete

Tags: regex, excel, vba

So what I'm attempting to do, is to use regex to compare columns, and if conditions are met, then render what is listed into a particular column(s).
The output of the `ReGex` is displayed in a `Results` sheet in column `Y`.
The `ReGex.pattern = "\d+"`.

The code ran as expected, until it reached:

```
RXt2Tm = RXt2MT(0) + T2Co
```

Where it has an error:

> "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.

My first inclination is to think that current code is expecting a number, but the actual answer is `"Not Applicable"`.
Do I need to alter the `InStr` or add another `If` and `ElseIf`?
How can I get this `ReGeX` to complete  - at least column `Y`.

Here is the code:

```vb
'COL Y RX:In
'T1
For MNum = 2 To RowNum

If InStr(1, WksT2.Range("JZ" & MNum).Value, "no charge", vbTextCompare) < > 0 Then
RXt1 = 0
T1Co = ""
' if copy has no charge, the value = 0
ElseIf InStr(1, WksT2.Range("JZ" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
RXt1 = WksT2.Range("JZ" & MNum).Value
T1Co = ""
'if copay don'
t contain not applicable, use copay value
Else: RXt1 = WksT2.Range("KC" & MNum).Value
T1Co = "%"
'otherwize, we use coinsurance
End If
  'T2
If InStr(1, WksT2.Range("KF" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
RXt2 = WksT2.Range("KF" & MNum).Value
T2Co = ""
ElseIf InStr(1, WksT2.Range("KF" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
RXt1 = WksT2.Range("KF" & MNum).Value
T2Co = ""
Else: RXt2 = WksT2.Range("KT" & MNum).Value
T2Co = "%"
End If

  'T3
If InStr(1, WksT2.Range("KL" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
RXt3 = WksT2.Range("KL" & MNum).Value
T3Co = ""
ElseIf InStr(1, WksT2.Range("KL" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
RXt1 = WksT2.Range("KL" & MNum).Value
T3Co = ""
Else: RXt3 = WksT2.Range("KN" & MNum).Value
T3Co = "%"
End If
  '    If InStr(1, WksT2.Range("?" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
'        RXt4 = WksT2.Range("?" & MNum).Value
'        T4Co = ""
'    Else: RXt4 = WksT2.Range("?" & MNum).Value
'        T4Co = "%"
'    End If

ReGex.Pattern = "\d+"
Set RXt1MT = ReGex.Execute(RXt1)
Set RXt2MT = ReGex.Execute(RXt2)
Set RXt3MT = ReGex.Execute(RXt3)
'RXt4mt = ReGex.Execute(RXt4)
RXt1Tm = RXt1MT(0) + T1Co
RXt2Tm = RXt2MT(0) + T2Co
RXt3Tm = RXt3MT(0) + T3Co 'RXt4Tm = RXt4MT(0) + T4Co
If InStr(1, RXt1, "deductible", vbTextCompare) < > 0 Or _
InStr(1, RXt2, "deductible", vbTextCompare) < > 0 Or _
InStr(1, RXt3, "deductible", vbTextCompare) < > 0 Then
Decider = "PlanDed-"
Else
Decider = ""
End If
If InStr(1, Decider, "planded", vbTextCompare) < > 0 Then
If IsNumeric(RXt1) = True Then
RXt1Tm = RXt1Tm & "*"
WksT3.Range("BY" & MNum + 1).Value = "*Deductible does not apply"
ElseIf IsNumeric(RXt2) = True Then
RXt2Tm = RXt2Tm & "*"
WksT3.Range("BY" & MNum + 1).Value = "*Deductible does not apply"
End If
End If
WksT3.Range("Y" & MNum + 1).Value = Decider + RXt1Tm & "G/" & RXt2Tm & "PB/" & RXt3Tm & "NPB"
If InStr(1, WksT2.Range("B" & MNum), "HSA", vbTextCompare) < > 0 And _
InStr(1, WksT2.Range("JT" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) < > 0 Then
RXt1Tm = (100 - RXt1MT(0)) & "% After Ded."
WksT3.Range("Y" & MNum + 1).Value = RXt1Tm
End If
Next MNum


COL Y RX:In
            'T1
            For MNum = 2 To RowNum

                If InStr(1, WksT2.Range("JZ" & MNum).Value, "no charge", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                    RXt1 = 0
                    T1Co = ""
            ' if copy has no charge, the value = 0
                ElseIf InStr(1, WksT2.Range("JZ" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    RXt1 = WksT2.Range("JZ" & MNum).Value
                    T1Co = ""
            'if copay don't contain not applicable, use copay value
                Else: RXt1 = WksT2.Range("KC" & MNum).Value
                    T1Co = "%"
            'otherwize, we use coinsurance
                End If
            'T2
                If InStr(1, WksT2.Range("KF" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    RXt2 = WksT2.Range("KF" & MNum).Value
                    T2Co = ""
                ElseIf InStr(1, WksT2.Range("KF" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    RXt1 = WksT2.Range("KF" & MNum).Value
                    T2Co = ""
                Else: RXt2 = WksT2.Range("KT" & MNum).Value
                    T2Co = "%"
                End If

            'T3
                If InStr(1, WksT2.Range("KL" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    RXt3 = WksT2.Range("KL" & MNum).Value
                    T3Co = ""
                ElseIf InStr(1, WksT2.Range("KL" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    RXt1 = WksT2.Range("KL" & MNum).Value
                    T3Co = ""
                Else: RXt3 = WksT2.Range("KN" & MNum).Value
                    T3Co = "%"
                End If
            '    If InStr(1, WksT2.Range("?" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            '        RXt4 = WksT2.Range("?" & MNum).Value
            '        T4Co = ""
            '    Else: RXt4 = WksT2.Range("?" & MNum).Value
            '        T4Co = "%"
            '    End If

            ReGex.Pattern = "\d+"
            Set RXt1MT = ReGex.Execute(RXt1)
            Set RXt2MT = ReGex.Execute(RXt2)
            Set RXt3MT = ReGex.Execute(RXt3)
            'RXt4mt = ReGex.Execute(RXt4)
                RXt1Tm = RXt1MT(0) + T1Co
                RXt2Tm = RXt2MT(0) + T2Co
                RXt3Tm = RXt3MT(0) + T3Co
            'RXt4Tm = RXt4MT(0) + T4Co
                If InStr(1, RXt1, "deductible", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Or _
                    InStr(1, RXt2, "deductible", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Or _
                    InStr(1, RXt3, "deductible", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                    Decider = "PlanDed-"
                    Else
                    Decider = ""
                End If
                        If InStr(1, Decider, "planded", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                            If IsNumeric(RXt1) = True Then
                                RXt1Tm = RXt1Tm & "*"
                            WksT3.Range("BY" & MNum + 1).Value = "*Deductible does not apply"
                            ElseIf IsNumeric(RXt2) = True Then
                                RXt2Tm = RXt2Tm & "*"
                            WksT3.Range("BY" & MNum + 1).Value = "*Deductible does not apply"
                            End If
                        End If
                WksT3.Range("Y" & MNum + 1).Value = Decider + RXt1Tm & "G/" & RXt2Tm & "PB/" & RXt3Tm & "NPB"
                If InStr(1, WksT2.Range("B" & MNum), "HSA", vbTextCompare) <> 0 And _
                    InStr(1, WksT2.Range("JT" & MNum).Value, "not applicable", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                   RXt1Tm = (100 - RXt1MT(0)) & "% After Ded."
                WksT3.Range("Y" & MNum + 1).Value = RXt1Tm
                End If
            Next MNum
```

[image: IMG1]
[image: IMG2]

Comment: Format the question with some line breaks to make it readable.

Comment: What type of variable is `RxT2Tm`? What is contained in `RXt2MT`, `RXt2MT(0)` and `T2C0`?

Comment: Is the indentation of the code correct? Also are the quotation marks within the code correct? - it seems there is a mismatched quote somewhere, as `'COL Y RX:In` has a leading quote, but `COL Y RX:In` does not. Please `edit` to fix code indentation and quote inconsistencies. Remember, the first 4 spaces of indentation on each line is to indicate that it is code, as opposed to text, so any lines with *no* indentation will be rendered as text instead of code.  After that, choose a number of spaces to use consistently for each level of code indent/unindent, for easy readability.